Drools , sum of spends in each Year
I have a main form called contract details which has a field called total spend tracking.
This field needs to get updated based on the sub form called financial year which has fields year and spend . I need to update the total spend tracking. As im very new in using Drools using Mvel dialect i have written below script which is not working.
Could anyone please help me with this.
Thanks a lot in advance
package com.bmssolutions.analytics;
dialect "mvel"
import java.util.List;
import com.bmssolutions.analytics.ContractDetails;
import com.bmssolutions.analytics.FinancialYear;

rule "Sum of spend tracking"

when

$contractDetails: ContractDetails(currentObject, $totalSpend: totalSpendTracking)
$sum : Number ()from accumulate( FinancialYear( $spend: spend ) from 
$contractDetails.financialYear;sum($spend))

then
$contractDetails.totalSpendTracking = $sum;  
end


JAVA is NOT JavaScript. I removed the tag.

There might not be many takers.

What do you mean by "is not working". Is the value wrong? What's the data in working memory when you execute your rules?

Also in this line $contractDetails: ContractDetails(currentObject, $totalSpend: totalSpendTracking) what is currentObject ? I'm surprised this rule compiles at all.
